# datetime.timedelta(x,y) returns TypeError on CoCalc.com but works elsewhere -- Why?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sage

My code works on onlinegdb.com but not on CoCalc.com.

```
import datetime
slowduration = datetime.timedelta(0,1)
print(slowduration)
```

Returns

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: sage.rings.integer.Integer
```

It isn't clear to me if this is a feature or a bug.

Comment: It appears that in your environment, `1` is something other than a normal Python integer.  You'll need to explain more what this `CoCalc.com` is and/or how it involves `sage.rings`, and what, if any code has been run already.  Another way to put it, this is not a [mcve].

Comment: No code besides that listed has been run except in the environment I'm using.

Thanks for your answer.  It's a Jupyter notebook hosted online and they allow you to use their server to do calculations.  I thought maybe the problem was with Jupyter or Sage and maybe someone would know.

I actually just can't call that one function in Python, I am not personally calling any other code so I guess the problem is server-side.

Comment: `timedelta` is doing, right away, `seconds += minutes/60 + ...`.

Comment: [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com) (for "Collaborative calculation in the cloud") is an online platform for computing and collaborating. Each CoCalc project is like a filesystem you create, that you can use with a full Ubuntu running in the cloud with tons of free software preinstalled. Basic usage is free, and paid upgrades can be purchased for more processors, memory, disk space... One thing CoCalc offers in particular is the ability to use Jupyter notebooks collaboratively, with a wide choice of Jupyter kernels preinstalled. One can also use LaTeX, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @kcrisman's answer and the "`int(0), int(1)`" trick...

Two other options if one wants to stick to the Sage kernel are

- (1) disable the preparser with `preparser(False)`,
- (2) append `r` (for "raw") to the integers, eg `datetime.timedelta(0r, 1r)`.

See also similar questions and answers around Sage's preparsing of floats and integers:

- (a) [Stack Overflow question 40578746: Sage and NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40578746)
- (b) [Stack Overflow question 28426920: Unsized object with numpy.random.permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28426920)
- (c) [Stack Overflow question 16289354: Why is range(0, log(len(list), 2)) slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289354)

Finally, note that code can be loaded into Sage from external files using either:

- `load('/path/to/filename.py')`
- `load('/path/to/filename.sage')`

where `.sage` files will get "Sage-preparsed" while `.py` files will not.

This gives a third option to bypass the preparser: load code from a `.py`file.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has a problem like this - It turns out that I was using the Sage math kernel and not the Python math kernel.  This website offers something like 15 different kernels.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob's self-answer is correct; here are a few more details.

In SageMath there is something called a preparser which interprets things so that integers are mathematical integers, not Python ints.  So [for example](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrKEotSCwqTtVQN9Q2VNcEACu7BI8=&lang=sage):

```
sage: preparse('1+1')
'Integer(1)+Integer(1)'
```

There is a lot more that involves - try `preparse('f(x)=x^2')` for some real fun.  But yes, it's a feature.

To fix your problem within the Sage kernel, though, you could just do [this](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLzC3ILypRSEksSS3JzE3l5SrOyS9PKS1KLMnMz1OwhUvogYiU1JySRI3MvBINA00dEGWoqcnLVVAEYiLr0wQAV7Qe0g==&lang=sage):

```
import datetime
slowduration = datetime.timedelta(int(0),int(1))
print(slowduration)
```

to get `0:00:01` as your answer.